# Procedure execution failed 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my first Stored Procedure in MySQL Database.

I need update thousands of rows and with traditional sql query the database is crashed.

I thinked update these thousands of rows using limit syntax, but I have error following :

> Procedure execution failed 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Can you help me ?

```
BEGIN

REPEAT

    UPDATE `tbl_01` jjj
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            t1.idticket,
            MAX(t1.ass) AS date_hour_ass
        FROM
            tbl_02 t1
        GROUP BY
            t1.idticket
    ) AS kkk
    SET jjj.date_hour_ass = STR_TO_DATE(
        kkk.date_hour_ass,
        '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'
    )
    WHERE
        jjj.date_hour_ass IS NULL
    AND jjj.idticket = kkk.idticket LIMIT 100000;

    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;

    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Reference Manual documents this restriction for UPDATE statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

excerpt:

> For multiple-table syntax, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` cannot be used.

---

One possible workaround is to avoid a join, and use a correlated subquery. That's not optimal from a performance standpoint, but performance should be predictable with a suitable index available

```
... ON `tbl_02` (`idticket`,`ass`)
```

It's a bit odd that we are getting the maximum value of a string, expecting a date value represented in format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Compared as string values, `'30/03/2019'` is greater than `'25/06/2019'`. That's significantly different than the result we'd get comparing *date* values.

June 25th (`'2019-06-25'`) "is greater than" March 3rd 2019 (`'2019-03-30'`)

Maybe that's what we want, the greatest string value comparing the day value first, before comparing month, with or without leading zeros. I don't know what we're trying to achieve. I'm guessing that we might actually want the maximum date value, but that's just a guess.

```
  UPDATE `tbl_01` t
     SET t.date_hour_ass = ( SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(s.ass,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))
                               FROM `tbl_02` s
                              WHERE s.idticket = t.idticket
                           )
   WHERE t.date_hour_ass IS NULL
   LIMIT 100000
```

Note that the `LIMIT` clause is a limit on the number of rows matched, not the number of rows changed. We're not seeing any guarantee that there won't be rows in `tbl_01` that won't have NULL values, even after the UPDATE statement processes it. e.g. there could be no matching rows in tbl_02 so the subquery returns NULL.

So there's potential for this statement to match 100,000 rows and have zero rows changed, so `ROWS_AFFECTED()` could return 0 even when there are more rows in `tbl_01` that could be updated.

An ugly fix to that would be include a condition on the same subquery in the WHERE clause.

```
  UPDATE `tbl_01` t
     SET t.date_hour_ass = ( SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(s.ass,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))
                               FROM `tbl_02` s
                              WHERE s.idticket = t.idticket
                           )
   WHERE t.date_hour_ass IS NULL
     AND
                           ( SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(s.ass,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))
                               FROM `tbl_02` s
                              WHERE s.idticket = t.idticket
                           )
         IS NOT NULL
   LIMIT 100000
```

What about rows in `tbl_01` that have a non-NULL value for `date_hour_ass` but the subquery will return NULL, or a different value than the one currently assigned? Are we at all concerned about updating those rows?